# Node js - ejs: How to run password check on login/register form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ejs

I created a login page as a small example.
The form is asking the usual things such as username, password etc, it also asks the user to confirm a password, and if the length is different it should throw an error warning the user about the discrepancy.

It is working If I enter the correct `password` and `confirm password` length,

It is **not working** if `password` is unequal to `confirm password` and the error looks like this:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "/register" in views directory
>   "/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/views"
>       at Function.render (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
>       at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express-ejs-layouts/lib/express-layouts.js:77:18)
>       at /home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/routes/users.js:30:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
>       at router (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
>       at /home/emanuele/Desktop/cashman-tracker-dashboard/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7

Below is the code with the related checks:

**users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Login Page
router.get('/login', (req, res) => res.render('login'));
// Register Page
router.get('/register', (req, res) => res.render('register'));

// Register Handle
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
    let errors = [];

    // Check required fields
    if (!name || !email || !password || !password2) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Please fill in all fields' });
    }
    // Check password
    if (password !== password2) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Passwords do not match' });
    }
    // Check password length
    if (password.length < 6) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Password should be at least 6 characters' });
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render('register', {
            errors,
            name,
            email,
            password,
            password2
        });
    } else {
        res.send('pass');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**register.ejs**

```
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <h1 class="text-center mb-3"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>Register</h1>
            <% include ./partials/messages %> //<-- This seems to be the cause of error
            <form action="/users/register" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input
                    type="name"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter Name"
                    value="<%= typeof name != 'undefined' ? name : '' %>" 
                    />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input
                    type="email"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter Email"
                    value="<%= typeof email != 'undefined' ? email : '' %>"
                    />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Create Pasword"
                    value="<%= typeof email != 'undefined' ? password : '' %>"
                    />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input
                    type="password"
                    id="password2"
                    name="password2"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Confirm Pasword"
                    value="<%= typeof email != 'undefined' ? password2 : '' %>"
                />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
            </form>
            <p class="lead mt-4">Have An Account? <a href="/users/login">Login</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**messages.ejs**

```
<% if(typeof errors != 'undefined'){ %> 
    <% errors.forEach(function(error) { %>
      <%= error.msg %>
    <% }); %> 
<% } %>
```

If it is useful I am also attaching a print screen of my project tree:

[image: tree]

The problem seems to be the following statement below in the **register.ejs** but I don't know

```
        <% include ./partials/messages %>
```

I don't know if the **messages.ejs** could also be related to the error

**What I have done so far:**

I looked at different sources, and [the official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ejs-layouts#usage) is the one I used. I double checked many times but the error still persists and as soon as I enter a password of length X and confirm password of length X+1 I have that strange error.

I am not sure if the error could be related to the **messages.ejs** or to the statement `<% include ./partials/messages %>` or if it could be something else.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been try your code and it's working fine, the only one line not working is:

```html
<% include ./partials/messages %>
```

You have to change this line with this code below:

```html
<%- include('partials/messages') %>
```

I hope it can help you.